# unable to require('aws-iot-device-sdk') using browserify.

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, browserify, aws-iot

Hi we are unable to use require('aws-iot-device-sdk') using browserify in nodejs application, error as follows -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

from bundle.js

Answer (score 0):

We were able to package aws-iot-device-sdk using browserify by doing the following:

1. npm install -g browserify (only required once to install browserify)
2. mkdir project
3. cd project
4. create main.js:
   `var awsiot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk'); console.log('success');`
5. npm install aws-iot-device-sdk
6. browserify main.js -o bundle.js

One thing we did notice is that one of the files our package depends on has some characters in it which are not recognized by the browser; we were able to fix this by adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in our html prior to referencing the bundle.